# Android OpenGL es transformation pixel

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm don't understand how we can positioning objects with opengl. All transformation values is between "-1.0f" - "1.0f". I'm made some game using with surfaceview. And I can simply change and defined objects x and y position. example; if android screen width is 480px, so my box max x values is 480. but how can I do this on opengl? How make the limits and how use pixel or dpi metrics? how can I change a box position on my finger touch place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, glTranslate and most if not all transformation values are not restricted to values between "-1.0" to "1.0". Being able to move an object 10px to the left or right is going to require setting up your transformation matrices properly. Below is the order of how OpenGL manipulates vertexes you give it.

[(4x4) Projection]*[(4x4) View]*[(4x4) Model]*[(4x1) your vertex]

You would probably want to use glOrtho(0.0,width,0.0,height,-1.0,1.0) to setup your Projection matrix. You can leave the View matrix as the identity matrix. Finally, you can use your model matrix to translate, rotate, and scale your objects at a pixel scale. Now a glTranslatef(10.0,0.0,0.0) on the Model matrix should move your object 10px in the x direction. Alternatively, you could leave the Model matrix as the identity matrix, and let your vertexes represent pixel coordinates.

You can look at this powerpoint, and on slide 4 you can see a nice graphic detailing whats happening to your vertexes. https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/download/attachments/195761441/OpenGL.pptx?version=1&modificationDate=1326820017000

Comment: `The method glOrtho(double, int, double, int, double, double) is undefined for the type GL10` change `glOrthof` or `glOrthox` ?

Comment: You have to use either glOrthof or glOrthox. I only used glOrtho as a way to generalize my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to change the position of an item in openGL you use [glTranslate](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and for the size you can set the size of the rectangle you are using whenever you are drawing it but as far as I know, you cannot limit the size of an object, but you could do some check before drawing the rectangle/box to know if the size the user want to resize is bigger than your Android device screen, and if so then do nothing (or you could show a toast telling the user that it cannot get bigger)

Also this could help you, [relation between pixels and gl.gltranslatef(floatx,y,z)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794281/in-opengl-how-can-i-get-relation-between-pixels-and-gl-gltranslateffloatx-y-z?answertab=votes#tab-top) but allow me to quote a bit of it:

> As such, when you do a glTranslate, the distance by which a particular
>   object will move (in terms of pixels) will depend on its distance from
>   the viewer. The further away it is from the viewer, the fewer pixels a
>   particular sideways or up/down will translate to.

Comment: yes, glTranslate change position, but this methods values between "1.0", "-1.0". how can I move to 10px right? or move to my touch position a object?